# How to add a priority in pytest for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, pytest

I have pytest tests. I run them in Azure DevOps pipeline. I have test results in Tests tab.
I want to add priorities (severities) to my tests in such a way their priorities are displayed in this Tests tab in the Priority field  (the red arrow in the screenshot). How can I do it? Some plugins?
[image: Azure DevOps pipeline Tests tav]